# Aligning two DIVs horizontally where one DIV is a constant width

Tags: html, css

I want to create two DIVs, a container DIV (which contains arbitrary content) and an arrow DIV which allows the user to scroll the content horizontally.

Ignoring the Javascript aspect, the basic layout and CSS could be something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

.outer-wrapper {
    min-width:275px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    height: 40px;
}

.container {
    width: 90%;
    min-width:100px;
    margin-left: 0.5em;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    float: left;
}

.inner-content {
    margin-top: 10px;
    white-space: no-wrap;
    position: relative; 
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.inner-element {
    display: inline-block;
}

.arrow {
    margin-top: 12px;
    min-width: 30px;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 2px;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class = "outer-wrapper">
        <div id = "container" class = "container">
            <div class = "inner-content" id = "inner-content">
                Options Options Options Options Options Options Options Options Options 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id = "arrow" class = "arrow">
            &#x25b6;
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's a jsfiddle link showing the rendering: **http://jsfiddle.net/RSTE9/1/**

The problem I have is that, ideally, I'd like the DIV containing the arrow to be as small as possible, so that most the width of the screen is comprised of the container DIV.

To achieve this, I thought I'd set the container DIV to a width of like `98%`, and the arrow DIV to a width of like 2%.  Unfortunately, this causes the arrow DIV to wrap to the next line on smaller screen sizes.

The essential problem is that I want the arrow DIV to always take up a very small portion of the screen, but I can't find a way to do this using percentages.  If the screen width is large, the arrow DIV always takes up too much space.  But if the screen width is very small (say on a mobile device), the arrow DIV might be pushed to the next line.  I played around with different percentage values, but there's seemingly no way to get an ideal value.  I settled at a width of `90%` - this looks good on small screens, but on a large screen it means the arrow DIV is taking up 10% of the screen!

I was thinking of using CSS3 media queries to adjust the percentages dynamically, but I am wondering if there is some easier solution that I'm just not thinking of.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that using css calc would be the answer:
[CSS Calc on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

give the arrow div a fixed size and the container a calc(100%-30px):

```
.container {
    width: calc(100%-30px);
    min-width:100px;
    margin-left: 0.5em;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    float: left;
}
```

Here is an example on jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/RSTE9/5/

Notice I removed a few of the options options so you can see the effect better.
You do have a minimum width on the main container, which prevents more collapsing.

Comment: css is becoming hardcore :)

Comment: Maybe someday we won't need jQuery ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why not set width of container as "*"?

```
   .container {
        width: *;
        min-width:100px;
        margin-left: 0.5em;
        margin-right: 0.5em;
        height: 40px;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
        float: left;
    }
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RSTE9/6/

Comment: That will cause the arrow DIV to wrap on smaller screen sizes

Answer (score 0):

seems like you messed a bit with float , display and white space.

display and white space is a good clue, width  a little less.

the idea is:

set the block container width no width nor overflow, but margin and white-space,

for inner content, reset white-space to normal , use display instead float.

Set min-width to text-content (100% - margin given to container)

Finally , vertical-align on both inline boxe containers text + arrow.

```
.outer-wrapper {
    min-width:275px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin:0 1%;
}
.container {
    min-width:98%;
    margin-left: 0.5em;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    min-height: 40px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    display:inline-block;
    white-space:normal;
}
.arrow {
    font-size: 10px;
    width:1em;
    text-align: right;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GCyrillus/2e3du/1/